# Having multiple words cycle through using Textillate JS

Tags: jquery

Using the [Textillate plugin](https://github.com/jschr/textillate) ([demo here](http://jschr.github.io/textillate/)), I want to be able to cycle through a group of words/phrases. Currently I'm able to get 2 words/phrases (max amount I want to show) to show and perform the animation I want, but when I add a third, it shows up as a third word/phrase on the same two words as a third line. How can I have it so it cycles through the the first 2 words/phrases and then the next 2?

HTML:

```
<div class="phrase-a">
   <p class="tlt">This is the first phrase</p>
</div>

<div class="phrase-b">
   <p class="tlt">This is the second phrase</p>
</div>

<div class="phrase-c">
   <p class="tlt">This is the third phrase</p>
</div>

<div class="phrase-d">
   <p class="tlt">This is the fourth phrase</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.phrase-a .tlt').textillate({
    in: {
        shuffle: false,
        sync: true
    },
    out: {
        effect: 'fadeOutRightBig',
        shuffle: false,
        sync: true
    }
)};
```

Comment: Can you change the HTML layout? If you want to cycle through a number of expressions, having only one of them visible at the same time, you can use a list.

Comment: Right, having them show one at a time is possible but I want to show 2 phrases at a time (which I've got to work). However, I want to also show others. For instance, I want Phrase A and B to show first, then Pharse C and D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get something which I believe is the desired effect by using a different layout:

HTML:

```html
<h1 class="tlt">
    <ul class="texts">
        <li>Some Title</li>   
        <li>Another Title</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="texts">
        <li>Some Title2</li>   
        <li>Another Title2</li>
    </ul>
</h1>
```

JS:

```
$('.texts').textillate({
    minDisplayTime: 1000, 
    in: { effect: 'flipInX', sync: true }, 
    out :{  delay: 3, effect: 'lightSpeedOut', sync: true},
    loop: true
});
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/kavTe/#base).

Comment: How can I make it so that rather than having both phrases having the same effect, I can make the top have a flip and the bottom a fade effect?

Comment: In this case, you can have 2 instances, as done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/kavTe/2/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and patience, MasterAM. I definitely appreciate you helping me out. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. Finding this library might even prove useful for me, too :)